# Fieldset inside fieldset

Tags: html

I think it is not allowed to have embedded fieldsets (fieldset
inside another fieldset) - but I would like to confirm that.

Answer (score 85):

```
<!ELEMENT FIELDSET - - (#PCDATA,LEGEND,(%flow;)*) -- form control group -->
```

[Fieldset must contain a legend followed by zero or more %flow elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.10)

```
<!ENTITY % flow "%block; | %inline;">
```

Flow includes %block

```
<!ENTITY % block
 "P | %heading; | %list; | %preformatted; | DL | DIV | NOSCRIPT |
  BLOCKQUOTE | FORM | HR | TABLE | FIELDSET | ADDRESS">
```

Block includes FIELDSET

It is fine.

Comment: WHATWG says it in plain english: [You can also nest fieldset elements.](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#the-fieldset-element)

Answer (score 29):

Yes, you can.  The W3C validator at http://validator.w3.org/ is happy with this:

```
<html><head><title>test</title></head>
<body><form action='go'>
<fieldset><legend>1</legend>
    <fieldset><legend>2</legend>
    <input type='text'>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yep you can do that. more info http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/fieldset

Answer (score 3):

No, it's legal.

Answer (score 1):

This is legal and in fact I have used it a number of times